# Add a line break using MySQL search & replace

Tags: mysql, wordpress, search, replace

I just migrated a SMF forum to WordPress BBPress.  The problem is video urls in posts are not on their own line so WordPress shows the url instead of displaying the video.

I'd like to do a search and replace in the database and put in a return before any YouTube url.

Example:

```
What do you think???https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbbM_v2_5wA
```

Would become:

```
What do you think???
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbbM_v2_5wA
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on a backup instance of your data first as it may not do exactly what you expect; in short the below will replace every FIELD containing the string 'https://www.youtube.com/' with the same string cut by a newline preceeding the url. If you run the code twice on your data it WILL insert a second newline, which is probably not what you want.

```
update TABLENAME set FIELD = concat(substring(FIELD, 1, locate('https://www.youtube.com/', FIELD)-1),'\n',substring(FIELD, locate('https://www.youtube.com/', FIELD))) where locate('https://www.youtube.com/', FIELD) > 0;
```

You will need to change identifiers `TABLENAME` and `FIELD` to reflect your schema.

Comment: It worked great.  Thank you for showing me how that is done.